# We need to be able to flag problematic Documentation tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, documentation

Someone has just created the Documentation tag [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css3) (they didn't even capitalize it …) which is problematic because it should not exist. "CSS3" topics should be covered within the existing [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css) Documentation tag.

There's no need for it to have its own section, and if there is, it should be handled in the "Versioning" section of CSS (an ability described by the Documentation Tour).

However, there's no Flag option on a tag or even an article/example to bring the tag to the attention of moderators/staff.

Can we please get the option to somehow bring tags or at least articles in Documentation to moderator attention?

The possible dupe above only covers a corner case of this topic.

Comment: Awesome! I knew this day would come. Cue "What even *is* CSS3 anymore?" questions all around.

Comment: (I jest, but there *is* actually a [factual and objective answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637901/is-css3-an-official-standard/8637917#8637917) to that question. It's just not what most web developers think it is.)

Comment: @BoltClock Tell me how you feel about http://css4-selectors.com/

Comment: I refuse to acknowledge its existence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documentation should actively reject pledge to "versioned" tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags) I know they were, umm... different beasts, but they say that you need to create a meta post asking for this instead of a flag.

Comment: @Braiam Nah, the upcoming feature in the accepted answer here explains the eventual process for this.

Comment: What about honestly, cleanly, completely, impeccably, unobstructedly and unheartbrokeningly* pointless tags like [**string**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/string/topics)? (*: I needed a brütäl wörd there, sorry for the faint of heart.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This planned change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th) should solve it:

> **Tag merges and aliases** for Documentation.  We will be adding a mapping from related tags to “master” tags (like [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python-2.7/topics) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python-3.x/topics) are related to the “master” [python](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics)).  Such a mapping will migrate existing topics to the master tag and prevent re-opening the aliased tag for Documentation.  Initially we (Stack Overflow employees) will be doing these by hand; it may be opened to moderators and high rep users up in the future.

Comment: I think no amount of aliasing and merging is going to fix the [**string**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/string/topics) tag... We need to be able to curate the tags too. There is an unbelievable amount of junk getting created... Probably we should be able to lock tags?

Answer (score 4):

Although there isn't any flag option for tags, there is an option to flag topics.

[image]

And it opens this dialog box:

[image]

You can select the "in need of moderator intervention" option and add optional details to explain that the tag need to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize "in need of moderator intervention" was an option under that flag. I've flagged that topic for mods to look at the whole CSS3 subject on Docs.

Comment: @TylerH I used the "unnecessary" option as it also goes to the moderators

Comment: Where do you see that info? I did received a notification and have the ability to delete the topic itself, though.

Comment: @TylerH yeah you are right , the "uncessary" option goes to users who don't have the rights to delete tags. The "in need of moderator intervention" seems better for this situation. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Just FYI, at the moment us regular mods don't see flags for Documentation entries - only the staff has access to them as no mod tools have been built for all diamond users yet.

Comment: @BoltClock Seems like Docs went public Beta too soon.

Comment: I can't see this