# Documentation should actively reject pledge to "versioned" tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics

Someone is trying to create the [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java-8/commit) topics, which would essentially duplicate the efforts of the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/topics) proper ones. I think documentations should actively reject such attempts with a helpful message like:

> You are trying to create topic-version, but topic already exist. You may want to join topic instead.

Actually someone managed to get 5 users to pledge for the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/807) tag...

Comment: People that wants to solve the python-3.x problem may just handle the petition here https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/807

Comment: Moving topics and merging tag's documentation is something we're gonna have to tackle soon, which should address this feature-request.

Comment: @KevinMontrose actually, it wouldn't because those people would be wasting their time if the "content" they are going to write in documentation is already in their specific language tags. What you describe is a reactive solution, mine is a proactive one. We should make sure people doesn't waste their time.

Comment: Once such tooling exists I expect we will _pre-emptively_ merge versioned tags into existing ones, not wait til they are created.  Have to build the tooling first though.

Comment: While they overlap, java-8 is majorly different from java-7 and how you do certain things in both versions of the language is different and needs to be documented differently. I think there is a genuine need to associate software documentation with versions explicitly. Most software vendors version both their software and documentation for this reason.

So, I'd argue that all documentation needs to be explicitly tagged with a version or version range of the stuff it applies to. 

Stackoverflow needs a way to do this. Hashtags probably are not the best way.

Comment: @JillesvanGurp there's no "hashtag" concept on the entire SE.

Comment: semantics, python-3 is what I would call a hashtag

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We now have a way to alias tags for the purposes of documentation.  This is currently restricted to SO developers and CoGro team members (it pretty ugly, and kind of dangerous) - so ask on meta if you need an alias.  We're going through and cleaning up existing stuff right now.

When a tag is aliased: all its content is moved to the survive tag, version information is stripped (since the versions applied no longer exist), redirects are setup for existing links, and any prior tag commitments are destroyed.  Future proposals to open the aliased tags for documentation are rejected.

Links from Q&A to Documentation are aware of aliases, so if you go to [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) for example you'll now see a pointer to [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)'s Documentation.

[image]

Comment: what about less-obvious stuff? java vs java-8 is just a different version. android vs android-gradle (those two are separate documentations) are related but one is just a part of the other.

Comment: @DanieleSegato this is one where I think we (Stack Overflow) should defer to those active in the tag.  Does it make more sense for those to be separate, or together?  By default they're separate, a well received argument in a meta post could get them merged.

Comment: Could you alias [tag:ecmascript], [tag:ecmascript-3], [tag:ecmascript-5], [tag:ecmascript-6] and [tag:ecmascript-7] to [tag:javascript]? (documentation wise)

Comment: First of all, is it needed for each merge request to be created as separate Q or should they all be posted here in comments? Also if each should be separate, then maybe some prefixed should be used?

Comment: @KevinMontrose ^ - didn't get response. Also could you alias [angularjs-directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-directive), [angularjs-controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-controller), [angularjs-animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-animation) to [angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)? In short all `angularjs-*` tags to [angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs). Thank you.

Comment: @Eugene if I read it correctly, you need to ask a meta question instead.

Comment: @Eugene first you need to take care of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296857/248058.