# Should the java-8 tag exist at all in documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I found the [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) tag and figured its purpose was to cover features introduced in Java 8, so added a new topic "Lambda expressions" and an introductory example.

This has been flagged as a duplication of content as it turns out the the plain [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag has already become home to topics such as lambdas and streams, and so the downvotes are already accumulating on my proffered example.

If the [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) tag is not intended to cover language features introduced by Java 8, then what is its purpose? Should it exist at all?

And is there a way to move the example I created in [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) so that it can be found in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), or should I simply delete this example altogether?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I flagged everything there as unnecessary or duplicating content since a couple of days now but it seems no-one is reviewing the flags... Moving examples is not currently possible AFAIK. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags

Comment: I understand the flags, but should the example be downvoted because it's in the wrong place? I thought that votes were intended to reflect the quality or accuracy of the example text, and I believe the example itself would be useful to someone getting started with lambda expressions. Shouldn't flags alone be used if the problem is one of tag suitability?

Comment: You can vote for any reason you want. "Unhelpful" is a common reason to downvote. Worry less about semantics. Click the downvote arrow if it looks wrong. And yes, also use flags. Documentation is a complete mess right now. No one thought it out well in advance.