# Tag that already exists in documentation

Tags: support, documentation

In the documentation, I have noticed a case of another tag for documentation of a language that already has its own tag.

[Main Swift documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topics)

[Additional Swift documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift2/topics)

Topics can be flagged if they already have existing documentation, however tags cannot (if tags is correct term?). [One post I read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329309/should-the-java-8-tag-exist-at-all-in-documentation), someone commented that they flagged every single topic as being unnecessary, but this doesn't seem like the right way to go about it. What would be the correct way to resolve this problem?