# Suggest deletion of redundant tags in Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

In Documentation, some tags might be redundant with others.

For example, for Python language we have:

- **Python Language**: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics
- **Python 2.7**: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python-2.7/topics
- **Python 3.x**: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python-3.x/topics

The last 2 tags are almost empty and totally redundant with the generic Python Language tag.

Is there a way in `Documentation` to flag to suggest a deletion for redundancy?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask on Meta for tags to be aliased with each other.  Yesterday, [Kevin released a change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags/329860#329860) that allows us to create an alias between a master tag and then other tags, but at this point it's a tool that is only available to SO developers and the Community Team.

If you have tags that need to be aliased, then create a Meta post asking for it.

Both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x are now aliases of Python Language.

Comment: This one counts?

Comment: It will @Braiam I'll update my answer once the tags have been aliased.

Comment: In the tagging systems I have created elsewhere, I was able to make some tags be subsidiary to others. E.g. Python 3.7 would be a child of Python, so any query of Python would return all of the items tagged Python 37 as well.  Similar to how Gmail pretends that labels are folders. Flat tagging systems are bogus.

Comment: @bluefeet I noticed tags for python versions have disappeared. Thanks