# Documentation Alias Request

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals, tag-alias-request

As per bluefeet's answer in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329953/4240221):

> If you have tags that need to be aliased, then create a Meta post asking for it.

Can we alias the following to [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) please:

- [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)
- [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba)
- [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba)
- [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba)
- [powerpoint-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-vba)
- [microsoft-project-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-project-vba)
- [visio-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visio-vba)
- [excel-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba-mac)
- [word-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba-mac)

Most of these aren't active in documentation yet, but hopefully they can be aliased *before* they get requested?

Comment: Good to think on your feet!

Comment: What exactly will "aliasing" them do?  While the syntax and some of the general methods obviously overlap, there are some distinctions (more between the underlying versions than with the overarching `vba`) that are still valuable to preserve

Comment: @RGA http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags/329860#329860 The idea being that everything sits under `vba` and we have _topics_ for things like excel or word etc... At the moment `excel-vba` is just getting filled with things that should be in `vba` anyway so rather than the constant clean-up it's easier to alias the tags rather than try and educate everyone that doesn't get the concept

Comment: SO MUCH YES.  ALL OF THE YES

Comment: @RGA we were talking about it for good while in the [VBA Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge) you should drop by some time :)

Comment: Also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags/329860#comment375166_329860

Comment: @Knu I think you would need to post as a question, I imagine they pick the requests up from question tags or something?

Comment: Yeah, a separate feature request would be good for that. Anything new requested in a comment is pretty much untrackable for us. Thanks. (cc @Knu)

Comment: @AdamLear http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336514/248058

Comment: @MacroMan _At the moment [tag:excel-vba] is just getting filled with things that should be in [tag:vba] anyway_ That is because the tag itself seems to imply some sort of special relationship to [tag:vba]. If the tag would be aliased (or [renamed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-very-bad-amalgam-tags-excel-vba-access-vba-word-vba-powerp)) to something language-neutral, and would include a few examples in other languages, that would go a long way to discouraging this kind of duplication.

Comment: @ZevSpitz There _is_ a special relationship. VBA exists primarily for MS Office automation...

Comment: @MacroMan By that logic, since all programs are meant for programming, then everything should be tagged [tag:programming].
In the end, 1) VBA is used for much more than just Office Automation (WIA, WMI, Regex, IE+MSHTML), and 2) automating Excel requires knowledge of a different object model than automating Word.

Comment: @ZevSpitz So your alternative proposal is a tag for "word-automation" that consists of examples of every possible language that can be used to automate word? Yes VBA can do all those other things - **from an Office application** - using it to do those tasks as it's sole purpose would be pointless. It's a specific language developed for a specific reason. It's not a general purpose OOP or scripting language and so it's specific enough to warrant its own tag.

Comment: Yes you can automate Office using C#.NET - you can do a whole manner of things with a .NET language because it's been designed to be used in a general way under a framework. You wouldn't develop a web app with VBA because it's not what it was designed for.

Comment: @MacroMan _examples of every possible language_ They would be examples of the Word object model not the language, and which languages would be used to demonstrate said parts of the API would depend on author interest and improvement requests.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Agree to disagree I think. At this moment in time there are already plenty of active contributors to the `vba` tag and I don't see any good reason to _not_ use office automation to illustrate examples of the language. By all means, create a tag for each COM library and start some examples. No reason that it has to be either/or when we can simply have both.

Comment: Examples could also use [tag:mshtml] or [tag:wia] or [tag:wmi], but that doesn't mean those tags should alias to [tag:vba].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127483/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-macro-man).

Comment: @ZevSpitz Again, VBA can do that amongst many other things. But it's _intended_ purpose is for Office Automation which isn't true of other languages. Just going around in circles here.  VBA was created with the intention to automate MS Office products. That's isn't true of any other language.

Comment: Consider: Javascript was intended to script web pages, but the DOM and the Javascript language are orthogonal concepts. So too [VBA and the specific object models](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33895910#33895910).

Comment: @ZevSpitz JavScript _was_ whereas VBA _was and still is_ - it's purpose in that sense hasn't changed. In any case this could go on forever until we actually get given a clear definition of what documentation is supposed to be. On that note, there's really nothing further for me to add that I haven't already expressed and so again I'll respectfully state that we shall have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score -2):

This is a terrible idea. All these object models can be consumed from languages other than VBA -- .NET lanugages, and other COM-supporting languages (e.g. Python, Delphi, C++).

It might be better to alias them away from [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). For example, [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba) and [word-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba-mac) should both alias to [word-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-automation), or [ms-word-activex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word-activex) or some similar variant.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of documentation. VBA is a language that can be documented. Word-Automation is far too broad and wouldn't sit well in documentation. Finally, VBA is a language specifically written for Office Automation so if you're not going to document its use with Office applications then what _will_ you document it with?

Comment: @MacroMan _Word Automation is far too broad_ So let's subsume it under [tag:vba] (and Excel / Powerpoint / Access / Outlook / Visio / Project automation as well. :) _Word Automation wouldn't sit well in documentation._ Why not? The Word Automation object model has objects such as `Application`, `Range`, and `Paragraph`, each representing a different part of the Word document or application. Unless you mean because each example is generally written in a single language? But that doesn't have to be the case, and the plan is to ...

Comment: @MacroMan [include a language switcher](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335491/111794) which would make multi-language examples easier to write.

Comment: You're missing my point entirely. The aim of this request isn't to document Excel/Word using VBA - but to document VBA under a single tag ("VBA") using Excel/Word etc as examples of the language _in use_. VBA shouldn't have a documentation example for "Excel.Range" but for the purpose of showing IntelliSense and the use of the "Set" keyword it would make sense to use that as an example.

Comment: @MacroMan So where would Excel Automation examples written in C# go? For some reason, questions about Excel Automation are tagged [tag:excel-vba] if they are written in VBA, but not if they are written in C#.

Comment: @MacroMan Aren't you proposing that the entire [tag:word-vba] be aliased into [tag:vba]?

Comment: Your point is around documenting Excel COM - I'm talking about documenting a specific language. Completely different things.

Comment: Yes, because word-VBA **is** VBA. It's just an _example_ of the same language. It doesn't require a separate tag in docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127460/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-macro-man).