# How do we document a service with multiple language-specific SDK's?

Tags: discussion, documentation-topics

The example I'm thinking of here is the [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) tag.

Now [AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) has SDKs for Android, CLI, JavaScript, iOS, Java, .NET, Node.js, PHP, Python, Ruby, Go, and C++.

Now major kudos to Amazon in that these SDK's are very standardised across the different languages. For the most part functions have the same names, parameters and return values. However, trying to write examples in all these languages is something that one person is unlikely able to do.

For example, I would be quite comfortable writing some examples for Simple Email Service in Java, but I wouldn't know where to start if you asked for a PHP example. Trying to create a language-agnostic example for one of these services would take a far braver man than I.

It seems that it would make more sense if you could create a topic for each language SDK. That way you've got all the Java documentation in one place, all the .NET documentation in one place and all the PHP documentation congealing and oozing in one place.

However currently, you've only got one [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) documentation tag. I feel like creating a separate topic per service per language would grow to be completely unmanageable. What options do we have here?

Comment: +1 for _congealing and oozing_.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with having one example for each language. I dare say this is a *great* use case for examples in a documentation topic.

> For example I would be quite comfortable writing some examples for Simple Email Service in Java, but wouldn't know where to start if you asked for a PHP example.

That's where someone who has experience with PHP and the respective SDK comes in. Remember that anyone can contribute an example to any topic. You don't have to be the one coming up with all the examples.

Comment: I am not sure that this answers the question. Let me pose a variation: Regular expressions are supported by .NET but the code to use them to access and manipulate multiple captured values is complex. Some examples would be good. Which topic should they be placed within? Candidates include 'C#', 'VB', '.NET', 'Visual Studio' and 'Regular expressions'.

Comment: @AdrianHHH For .NET libraries, the case for a single documentation is even stronger. The AWS SDKs are different assemblies, although Amazon works hard to keep them mostly the same. But different .NET languages target the same exact libraries, so the API surface is exactly the same. Any variation between languages has to do with the syntax of the language (`int` vs `Integer`, or `foreach` vs `For Each`) and not language-specific versions of the API. (I am not arguing that the AWS SDKs need separate documentation; in fact I think there should still be one documentation for all the SDKs.)

Answer (score 1):

Support for multiple lanugages in a single example is supposed to be coming:

From the [public beta announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta):

> **What’s to come**
>
> There are things we know we’re going to do that just weren’t ready in time for launch.
>
> - Code blocks with multiple languages (think MSDN’s C#/VB/F# switcher)

This would resolve the issue quite neatly; it would be straightforward to include multiple examples, one for each language / language binding.

Comment: @Comintern RE _*Everything* in VBA is using a COM library. The entire language is built around COM. The topic is overly general, and the single example is overly specific._ [http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/7186/using-com-libraries-in-vba](Using COM Libraries in VBA) (no other place to comment on this, but it's relevant to the question here) Would you put all the .NET examples within the C# documentation, because C# was built with .NET in mind, and because the language is just a thin layer connecting various assemblies, and you can't really do anything with the language on its own?

Comment: @Comintern  Or would you have a topic in C# on how to get up and running with an arbitrary .NET assembly (add a reference, use Nuget) with some example code using that assembly, and link to the assembly's actual examples? The same holds true for VBA -- there should be a single topic describing the use of COM libraries with one or two examples that show how to use some libraries, and links to the language-neutral COM examples.