# Remove ecmascript-6 tag from Documentation

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation, documentation-tags, tag-alias-request

There is an [ecmascript-6 tag in Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ecmascript-6). I think it should be deleted, because ECMAScript 6 is already covered in [JavaScript language](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topics).

Comment: Related [Documentation should actively reject pledge to "versioned" tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329860)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags/329860#comment375166_329860