# Capitalize 's' in Javascript in Documentation

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation, documentation-tags

The proper name of this language is *Java**S**cript*.

Could some high-rep user fix this issue?

The JavaScript documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topics

Comment: [It was *JavaScript* yesterday](https://web.archive.org/web/20161006093450/http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript). I have no idea who changed this and why.

Comment: The friendly name was set to *Javascript* yesterday, [see revision 46](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3624960/revisions). It didn't have a friendly name before, according to the diff at least, so no clue how it was *JavaScript* yesterday.

Comment: It was *JavaScript Language* to be precise, and that was its friendly name if you look at revision 44. And that history shows that @RobertHarvey made the change, despite it being spelled correctly throughout the excerpt and wiki below it...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Look again, the friendly name was *Java**s**cript Language* before, even though the Documentation page had *Java**S**cript Language*.

Comment: @Stijn Time to get a new pair of glasses ;). How does this even work?

Comment: "JavaScript is a trademarked brand name that refers to just one ECMAScript implementation."

Comment: @Knu. It could be an _ECMAScript_ tag as well for me (I just like the names to be spelt correctly). I believe that the discussion about the _ECMAScript_ tag deserves its own thread however. + http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332662/remove-ecmascript-6-tag-from-documentation?rq=1

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski It won't fly with noobs and the documentation is principally for them. That's a conscious and pragmatic choice that I respect.

Comment: Right. People shouldn't be forced to search for ECMAScript if they want JavaScript. Ehm, the search itself isn't case sensitive is it?

Comment: I changed it to `JavaScript`. Not sure how the name was working correctly given [revision 43](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3624960/revisions). Maybe 44 fixed it and the diff isn't rendered properly? In any case, the name seems good now.

Comment: @JonEricson is the hero Stack Overflow needs but not the one is deserves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been solved by Jon Ericson:

> I changed it to `JavaScript`. Not sure how the name was working correctly given [revision 43](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3624960/revisions). Maybe 44 fixed it and the diff isn't rendered properly? In any case, the name seems good now.