# Make [java-8] tag an alias of [java] in the Documentation

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation, documentation-tags, tag-alias-request

We [did see this coming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags), and it happened: documentation for [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java-8) tag was created. Currently it contains only one topic with one (downvoted) example and lots of improvement (deletion) votes.
Since we have a [feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags/329860#329860) to alias tags for the purposes of documentation, I suggest removing current [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java-8) content and making it an alias of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java).